# RC1015 error opening winresrc.h

Tags: c++, windows, dll, windows-phone-8.1

I have a cross platform c++ project. In this project I am using my dll's which are using .rc files. On Windows eveything works, but on Windows Phone it doesn't as the winresrc.h is not a part of Windows Phone sdk.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\\Include\windows.h(81): fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winresrc.h'.
```

How else can i use resources in native c++ libraries on Windows Phone platform ?